# std::set containing pair with custom comparator

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, stdvector, std-pair

I have a `vector < pair <double, int> >`, where `double` represents weight of a person and `int` represents the id of that person.

Now I need to convert it to `set < pair < double, int > >` to remove the duplicates based on the `id` of that person, but inside the vector I have data with some loose precision.

Example data:

```
-----------------------
    double |   int
-----------------------
    10.234 |  1     <--
    20.123 |  2
    10.2   |  1     <--
    30.33  |  3
```

As we can see, `id 1` has weights in different precision.

Using the default comparator of `std::set` will result in having 4 elements in the set, but I need only 3.

Only 1 element with `id 1` should be there in the set (anyone from the two competitors will do).

The reason I'm not using `std::map` is, because I need the entries to be in a specific sequence: I need them to be ordered by weight. For this reason, I'm using the following comparator:

```
struct comp__f {
    bool operator() (const pair<double, int>& lhs, const pair<double, int>& rhs) const{
        if(lhs.first < rhs.first) return true;
        if(lhs.first > rhs.first) return false;
        return lhs.second > rhs.second;
    }
};
```

**Note**: The question is still open, @Robᵩ's answer doesn't solve the problem entirely, but I appreciate his effort.

Comment: What is the "specific sequence" you need the set to have?

Answer (score 4):

Since a record cannot be less than itself, or its equivalent self, ensure that your comp function returns false if two records have the same ID, regardless of weight.

```
// Assuming that your previous comp_f was correct, here is the new one:
struct comp__f {
    bool operator() (const pair<double, int>& lhs, const pair<double, int>& rhs) const{
        if(lhs.second == rhs.second) return false;  // ADD THIS LINE
        if(lhs.first < rhs.first) return true;
        if(lhs.first > rhs.first) return false;
        return lhs.second > rhs.second;
    }
};
```

Comment: Adding that line will rearrange the order of the elements, but the set will still have 4 elements. no ?

Comment: @Jaydeep - No. Adding that line, the set will have only 3 elements. `set` will observe that `{10.234, 1} < {10.2, 1}` is false, and that `{10.2, 1} < {10.234, 1}` is also false. It will rightly conclude that the elemetns are identical, and refuse to insert the latter one. (At least, it would do so if it were anthropomorphic.)

Comment: @juanchopanza, you are right, I just read the docs. + I tried it just now, and it works for the sample example. Also is there any change of unusual behavior here, because I have a large amount of data, and using gdb I see the number of elements have reduced, but there still exist some elements with same id. I'm confused :/

Comment: @Jaydeep I am confused, too. I don't see any way that this comparison function can allow multiple elements with the same id. Can you reduce your program to the smallest possible program that demonstrates that error and copy-paste that small, complete program as an addition to your question?

Comment: @Robᵩ, please try this sequence http://paste.kde.org/pb90c1e42/ 
with the above comparator, I get two elements with id = 1

Comment: @Jaydeep  I'm wrong. My compare function does not provide the required strict weak ordering. Unless I come up with an alternative for you soon, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
#include<set>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class CustomComparitor
{
    public:
        int operator()(const pair<double,int>& lhs, const pair<double,int>& rhs)
        {
            return lhs.second < rhs.second;
        }
};
int main()
{
    set<pair<double,int>,CustomComparitor> myset;
    myset.insert(make_pair(1.4, 2));
    myset.insert(make_pair(1.5, 2));
    myset.insert(make_pair(1.6, 1));
    myset.insert(make_pair(1.4, 3));

    for(auto itr = myset.begin(); itr!=myset.end();itr++)
    {
        cout<<itr->first<<"  "<<itr->second<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems quite similar to what I answered 9 min. ago. But it turns out OP needs the elements to be ordered by weight.

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm late to the party, but I had a similar problem and I think I solved it. [Robᵩ was already on the right track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18767681/2675154), but your original lines need to be modified, too. All in all, I came up with the following comparator:

```
struct comp__f {
    bool operator() (const pair<double, int>& lhs, const pair<double, int>& rhs) const {
        return (lhs.second != rhs.second) && (lhs.first < rhs.first),
    }
};
```

As Robᵩ explained, the `(lhs.second != rhs.second)` part makes sure, that the IDs are unique. If this is guaranteed, then you just need to compare the weights using `<`. So, `(lhs.first < rhs.first)` ensures that the unique entries in the set get ordered by their weights.

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/u9QP66)